# Round down datetime values to previous 30 seconds using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

The Time Stamp give is in Seconds Precision. 
Eg:

```
myTime                 myVal
2019-06-03 11:47:37    0.34
2019-06-03 11:47:12    0.32
```

Give `myTime`  is `DateTime` object
Would like to adjust the time as `2019-06-03 11:47:30` , `2019-06-03 11:47:00` ie to previous 30 Second Precision.

One Function may be applied is

```
def timeAdjust(numSec):
    if numSec > 30:
        numSec = 30
    else:
        numSec = 0
    numSec
```

Challenge is to call the function, like

```
timeAdjust(df['myTime'].seconds) # Does not work ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dt.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) with "30s":

```
pd.to_datetime(df['myTime']).dt.floor('30s')

0   2019-06-03 11:47:30
1   2019-06-03 11:47:00
Name: myTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

For more information regarding date/time frequencies you can use here, check out [Offset Aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

---

If you want to write this as a reusable function, modify your code to accept two arguments: `qualifier`, and `freq` denoting the scale and frequency respectively.

```
def adjust_time(ser, qualifier, freq=1):
    return ser.dt.floor(f'{freq}{qualifier}')
```

Sample run,

```
adjust_time(pd.to_datetime(df['myTime']), qualifier='s', freq=30)

0   2019-06-03 11:47:30
1   2019-06-03 11:47:00
Name: myTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

It works nicely for other frequencies as well,

```
adjust_time(pd.to_datetime(df['myTime']), qualifier='D')

0   2019-06-03
1   2019-06-03
Name: myTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks..@cs95
But is there a way to Pass the time to custom Function.
In case I need some thing else in timeAdjust function to be done